# Rails/Jquery Drag-Drop Input Array

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have a simple form that I want to drag-drop to build a list.

The list below this form is a table of users: I want this to be an array of user_ids, but I'm not sure what the best way to do it is.

Should I have a hidden input that makes an array of ids via jquery? I've got UJS working on a lot of forms, so that's a need in this scheme.

Advice?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an array of ID's in a hidden field would make sense, with an event on sortable (is that what you're using?

```
$('#sortable_one').sortable({
  connectWith: '#sortable_two',
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    $('#hidden_field_one').val($('#sortable_one').sortable("serialize", { key: "sort" }));
    $('#hidden_field_two').val($('#sortable_two').sortable("serialize", { key: "sort" }));
  }
}
```

Comment: Just droppable. Sorting doesn't matter so much. I'm aggregating stats for groups--groups are created by dropping in a box. Got any recommendations for how to style a pretty drop-box? I'm thinking I may just use the bootstrap-tag plugin...